# Tortoisehg Error abort: unexpected response: empty string (bitbucket)

Tags: tortoisehg

I can't push changes to the repo (bitbucket). I am finding difficult to find the cause of the problem with this message:

```
E:\Umbraco\Railway Children\source>hg --repository "E:\Umbraco\Railway Children\
source" push --force --debug --verbose --time --traceback
pushing to https://bitbucket.org/BluefinDigital/railway-children
using https://bitbucket.org/BluefinDigital/railway-children
sending capabilities command
using auth.bitbucket.org.* for authentication
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
using auth.bitbucket.org.* for authentication
http auth: user fabiomilheiro, password ***********
using auth.bitbucket.org.* for authentication
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
query 1; heads
sending batch command
using auth.bitbucket.org.* for authentication
http auth: user fabiomilheiro, password ***********
using auth.bitbucket.org.* for authentication
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
searching for changes
all remote heads known locally
1 changesets found
list of changesets:
1786dddde618bbd5a5b508ada9671e49437d8072
bundling: 1/1 changesets (100.00%)
bundling: 1/1 manifests (100.00%)
bundling: Source/RailwayChildren.Web/Extensions/UCommerceUtils.cs 1/41 files (2.
44%)

...

bundling: www/xslt/ShopHome[XSLT].xslt 39/41 files (95.12%)
bundling: www/xslt/UpdatePayment[XSLT].xslt 40/41 files (97.56%)
bundling: www/xslt/XSLTsearch.xslt 41/41 files (100.00%)
sending unbundle command
sending 203588 bytes
using auth.bitbucket.org.* for authentication
sending: 64/396 kb (16.16%)
sending: 128/396 kb (32.32%)
sending: 192/396 kb (48.48%)
sending: 198/396 kb (50.00%)
sending: 198/396 kb (50.00%)
http auth: user fabiomilheiro, password ***********
using auth.bitbucket.org.* for authentication
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
sending: 262/396 kb (66.16%)
sending: 326/396 kb (82.32%)
sending: 390/396 kb (98.48%)
sending: 397/396 kb (100.25%)
sending: 397/396 kb (100.25%)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 88, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 740, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 514, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 830, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 801, in checkargs
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 737, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 471, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 4709, in push
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 1902, in push
  File "mercurial\wireproto.pyo", line 307, in unbundle
  File "mercurial\httppeer.pyo", line 203, in _callpush
ResponseError: ('unexpected response:', '')
abort: unexpected response: empty string
time: real 5.79
```

7 secs (user 0.421+0.000 sys 0.078+0.000)

What does that Response error mean? And why am I getting this?

Comment: JFYI - [Bitucket List Thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.mercurial.bitbucket.general/2326)

Answer (score 0):

The thread mentioned in the comments [is now here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131027080427/http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.mercurial.bitbucket.general/2326), and also involved "`abort: unexpected response: empty string`"

> Apparently, this was Bitbuckets way of letting me know I was over my user limit (After having a year of 10 users free).
>   I noticed it first when I logged in with the org account (which I hardly ever do).